# Django form is not displaying

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I am new to django forms and while trying to design an HTML form, I notice that the django form blocks are not displaying. Below are the codes:

`<body>` tag of index.html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="panel panel-login">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <a href="#" class="active" id="login-form-link">Login</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <a href="#" id="register-form-link">Register</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            {% block login_content %}
                            {% endblock %}
                            {% block register_content %}
                            {% endblock %}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`login.html` which goes into the `{% block login_content %}`

```
{% extends 'index.html' %}
{% block login_content %}
<form id="login-form" action="{% url 'authentication:user_login' %}" role="form" style="display: block;" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input id="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter Username" tabindex="1" class="form-control">

    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input id="password" type="password" name="password" tabindex="=2" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Login</button>

</form>
{% endblock %}
```

`register.html` that goes into the `{% block register_content %}`

```
{% extends 'index.html' %}
{% block register_content %}
    <form id="register-form" role="form" style="display: none;" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ user_form.as_p }}
        {{ profile_form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" name="" value="Register">
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

On my UI, the `{{ user_form.as_p }}` and the `{{ profile_form.as_p }}` does not appear at all.

When i inspect the console of my UI, the html does not even pick up the following line from the register.html:

```
<form id="register-form" role="form" style="display: none;" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
```

Here is the `login.js` which is responsible for the UI interactivity:

```
$(function() {

    $('#login-form-link').click(function(e) {
        $("#login-form").delay(100).fadeIn(100);
        $("#register-form").fadeOut(100);
        $('#register-form-link').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $('#register-form-link').click(function(e) {
        $("#register-form").delay(100).fadeIn(100);
        $("#login-form").fadeOut(100);
        $('#login-form-link').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

EDIT:
Here is my `views.py`:

```
def user_login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('homepage'))  # main page if login is successful

            else:
                return HttpResponse("ACCOUNT NOT ACTIVE")

        else:
            print('Someone tried to log in and failed')
            print('Username: {}, password, {}'.format(username, password))
            return HttpResponse('Invalid login details supplied')

    else:
        return render(request, 'authentication/login.html', {})

def register(request):
    registered = False

    if request.method == "POST":
        user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
        profile_form = UserProfileInfoForm(data=request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():

            user = user_form.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()

            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user

            if 'profile_pic' in request.FILES:
                profile.profile_pic = request.FILES['profile_pic']

            profile.save()

            registered = True

        else:
            print(user_form.errors, profile_form.errors)

    else:
        user_form = UserForm()
        profile_form = UserProfileInfoForm()

    return render(request, 'authentication/register.html',
                  {
                      'user_form': user_form,
                      'profile_form': profile_form,
                      'registered': registered
                  })
```

Okay, it seems like it is impossible to have a single page display both the templates. Is there anyway to get it done?

Comment: You should show your view. Which template are you actually rendering? You can't have two templates inheriting from a single base and expect them both to show.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I am trying to render the index.html. Is there a way to allow me display both registration form and login form on a single page?

Comment: can you post the views?? from where you are sending the form to the template

Answer (score 3):

In your `register.html`,

```
<form id="register-form" role="form" style="display: none;" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
```

You are setting `style="display: none;"`, so obviously the form won't show up.

EDIT: I am not sure about the feasibility of showing two different forms in the same page.

Comment: I have tried that as well, it doesnt show up. Daniel in my first post mentioned earlier that one view cannot render two different templates sadly.